# ProgressMessageBox Is Not Updating

Tags: gwt, gxt

In GXT (from Sencha) I am attempting to use a ProgressMessageBox to show the user that work is being done, but I am not seeing the message box until after **all** of the work is complete. Here is the code:

```java
final ProgressMessageBox messageBox = new ProgressMessageBox("Task Description",
                                                             "Executing Task...");
messageBox.setProgressText("Calculating...");
messageBox.setPredefinedButtons();
messageBox.show();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  for (long l = 0l; l < 10000000000l; ++l) {
    if (l == 12345l) {
      MyUtil.info(60, "" + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    }
  }
  messageBox.updateProgress((double)(i + 1) / 5, "{0}% Complete");
}
```

This code is in the `SelectionHandler` of a menu item. Obviously I am not actually just looping a few billion times in the "real" code, but when I perform the work that I want to execute I get the same result ... the message box is shown after all the work has been completed.  I see the "info" messages (`MyUtil#info` is simply a wrapper around the GXT `Info` capability, which causes an info message to be displayed for the specified number of seconds) ... and on my machine, running the code shown, each message has a value that is about seven seconds greater than the previous message (but they all show up at the same time as the message box).

Is there something that I need to do after calling `ProgressMessageBox#updateProgress` to force the screen or message box to refresh?

Comment: No, we do not need any refresh http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:messagebox,  follow the progress bar example here. It will help

Comment: Thanks Vivek ... I had looked at the example in the GXT Explorer Demo, which was a useful guide. Perhaps I need to control my processing using a timer, or maybe use the GWT `Scheduler` class to execute one request at a time?  I'll try that and add a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by putting the task into a `Scheduler#execute` method. The example in the Sencha Explorer Demo uses a `Timer`, but since I don't know how long the execution will take I chose to use the `Scheduler` approach. Here is the relevant final code:

```java
...
menuItem.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Item>() {
  @Override
  public void onSelection(final SelectionEvent<Item> selectionEvent) {
    final ProgressMessageBox messageBox = new ProgressMessageBox("Size All Columns", //
                                                                 "Resizing Columns...");
    messageBox.setProgressText("Calculating...");
    //  messageBox.setPredefinedButtons();
    messageBox.show();
    resizeNextColumn(messageBox,
                     _selectionModel instanceof CheckBoxSelectionModel ? 1 : 0,
                     _grid.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() - 1);
  }
});
...
private void resizeNextColumn(final ProgressMessageBox messageBox,
                              final int columnIndex,
                              final int lastColumnIndex) {
  Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
      resizeColumnToFit(columnIndex);
      if (columnIndex == lastColumnIndex) {
        messageBox.hide();
        _grid.getView().refresh(true);
        return;
      }
      messageBox.updateProgress((double)columnIndex / (lastColumnIndex + 1),
                                "{0}% Complete");
      resizeNextColumn(messageBox, columnIndex + 1, lastColumnIndex);
    }
  });
}
```

One thing that didn't appear to work is the `messageBox.setPredefinedButtons()` call ... when I use this the progress bar in the message box doesn't update at all. I really didn't want an "OK" button on the dialog, but for now it'll have to do. I'm using 3.1.0 of GXT.